# Search Console Not Validating CLS issue, My CLS is Zero from last 2 months

Tags: google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

My website CLS score is zero in google page speed insight lab data from last two months, i validate two times from search console, its getting failed again and again, any one can let me know what might be the issue ?

https://imperialrooms.co.uk/products/crushed-velvet-3-piece-beige-bedspread

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAJWM.png

Answer (score 1):

I think the point is how Search Console measures CLS data. Whereas FID and LCP are measured on page load only, CLS is measured all over the user session. That's why you can get more or less accurate lab data for FID and LCP, but can find massive differences for CLS between lab and field data.

You can read more details on how CLS measurement is held here: https://web.dev/evolving-cls/.

What I'd suggest is using [Chrome's Performance Devtool](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/evaluate-performance/) to record a session, and then interact with as many things in your page as you can. That way you'll be able to detect any CLS caused on user interaction.

But, even without analysing your page, I can tell that your reviews and "you may also like" sections cause a huge CLS, as they take quite some time to be ready, and they push the content below on load. Consider reserving the necessary space for them with CSS, by setting a min-height value to the container, for example.

Answer (score 0):

### Lab Data

A synthetic test, loads the page and does a few tests, it is purely a diagnostic tool.

### Origin Summary

Real world data collected from real browsers.

**This data is for the whole domain not just this page**

Also in the real world CLS data is collected from the second the page loads **until the page unloads**.

For this reason if you have layout shifts further down the page then they will show.

This data also includes multiple screen sizes so you may have a layout shift at a tablet screen size that the synthetic tests are not picking up.

Finally as "Origin Summary" is across the whole website not this one page, you could possibly have a page elsewhere that has a large CLS that is impacting your origin summary.

The final thing to note is that the Origin Summary shows you a mini bar graph where:

- 84% of page visits have a low CLS score (a pass)
- 4% of page visits have an average CLS score
- 12% of page visits have a poor CLS score

This points to either a poor performing page with a very high CLS or the site having issues at certain screen sizes.

You need to test for both of these.

You may want to consider using [the web vitals library](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals) to collect real world data and link it with screen size data, scroll data etc. in order to identify the cause of your CLS issues.